# A css issue, asking for help

Tags: css

Ask for help. I am a css novice, and made a template. The template shown above in IE7 normal; but in Mozilla Firefox above, there are misplaced situation. I should ask how to solve this problem?

This template presentation addresses: http://blog.512059.cn

**

In the # bgtop have added overflow: hidden;. Problem solved. Very grateful to prodigitalson and Eric Muyser help me

**

Comment: I looked at your linked website in IE8 and Firefox 3.5 - in both browsers, the webiste looks same and mis-aligned. Can you share a screenshot of the correct alignment of your template or can you explain what is your expected layout of the page?

Answer (score 3):

In order for `.bgtop` to expand with the length of the element inside you need to clear the floated elements. In this case the easiest way to do this is to set the width on `.bgtop` in pixels and then set the overflow to hidden.

```
.bgtop { width: 816px; overflow: hidden;}
```

there are a few other ways to clear floats, for additional methods google for "float clearing" or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to "overflow: hidden", you can solve float issues with "clear: both". Basically just insert a spacer at the bottom of the #page div:

```
<br clear="all" />
```

or

```
<br style="clear: both" />
```

The latter doesn't work for me in this case, without adding some text in the tag.

You could make it a div, and use CSS.

Comment: this will work but its better not to resort to extra markup unless absolutely necessary.